# Error while migrating JSP code from Windows to Linux machine

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I worked on a JSP code that is runnning on a Tomcat5.5 server in windows system .

I had to copy all the JSP code to a linux system and when I did the same I got an error stating below.

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: c:\tmp is not a directory
 Readcsv.init(Readcsv.java:36)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)


org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I modified a java code in the windows system without that c:\tmp directory and restarted the tomcat server and the tool worked fine.

When I replaced the modified java code of windows to the linux system, I still get the same error.

Note: Am accessing the linux server from windows using the url `http://192.168.0.85:8080/CNA/uploadcsv.jsp`where 85 is the system number of linux.

Is there anything like tomcat has to be restarted for the linux version too? If so how to do the same?

**UPDATE**

This is where I have used the c:\tmp location in my code.

```
public class Readcsv extends HttpServlet {
private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = "c:\tmp";
private File tmpDir;
private static final String DESTINATION_DIR_PATH ="/files";
private File destinationDir;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    tmpDir = new File(TMP_DIR_PATH);
    if(!tmpDir.isDirectory()) {
        throw new ServletException(TMP_DIR_PATH + " is not a directory");
    }
    String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH);
    destinationDir = new File(realPath);
    if(!destinationDir.isDirectory()) {
        throw new ServletException(DESTINATION_DIR_PATH+" is not a directory");
    }

}
```

How can I find the replacement for the temp path? The destination path works fine.
I exactly copied the code from this [example](http://www.jsptube.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html)

Comment: Are you asking how to restart Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Your servlet container should have javax.servlet.context.tempdir property defined have you tried using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hardcode disk file system paths in your code. That's only portability and maintainability trouble.

In case of temporary files, rather make use of [`File#createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
File tempfile = File.createTempFile("name", ".ext");
```

It will automatically create the temp file at the right location, regardless of the environment. You can however also obtain the tmp dir root location by `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");`.

---

In case of resources which are to be read by your application, just put them in the runtime classpath or add their path to the runtime classpath. Then you can just obtain them from the classpath by `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` methods on `Class` or `ClassLoader`.

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.properties");
```

If you really need to have a fixed path outside the classpath, then rather define it in a properties file so that you at least have *any* control over the path from outside the application (so, without the need to change the code everytime).

```
String path = properties.getProperty("my.file.path");
```

Comment: Just remove `fileItemFactory.setRepository(tmpDir);` It defaults to temp dir already. Another suggestion: follow Commons Fileupload own examples at their own homepage, not 3rd party ones.

Comment: @BalusC I felt like it requires a separate question. My requirement is more clear in that question. Can you just pitch in and solve my issue?

Comment: I already answered in the above comment that you don't need it.

Comment: I tried that. I would now like to know what to use in my TMP_DIR path? Because C:\\tmp is invalid location in a linux machine.

Comment: `private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");` I used this. But this worked fine with windows machine and when i uploaded the same compiled and executed application in linux machine, the file is not getting read. What might be the issue in this case?

Comment: Remove it. Remove all lines related to `tmpDir` stuff. You don't need it in this particular case. Commons Fileupload already uses the system temp dir by default (they get it as system property). If you ever want to create a temp file **manually**, use the way as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @BalusC Yes tmpDir stuff was not needed at all.. Thanks for your response. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081750/difference-in-reading-csv-file-in-unix-system-windows-system` If you can help me out in this question too, it would be of great use.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your application try to read a csv file under "C:\tmp" which doesn't exist on your linux system.

Comment: yes that is why i have changed the java code and copied the same to the linux system

Comment: what do you mean with "same" ? did you create a new order called "c:\tmp" on Linux ??? or did you create a new folder like /home/csvrepository/ for your csv and then copied all the csv files in that folder and modified your code?

Comment: after you modified your code, you have to compile and package your application (WAR) and redeploy on tomcat.

Comment: I have restarted tomcat in linux machine too.. But i havent compiled the java code there.. Neither I didnt do that in windows machine.. But in windows it worked.. In linux its not working..

Comment: It works probably because you still have a C:\tmp directory on Windows, although you didn't recompile your code. Change the name of directory to c:\tmp2 and modify the rows in your code appropriately. You will see that it won't work anymore. I think that you've problems with web application development (compiling, packaging, deployment). You have to compile your code and redeploy your app after you changed it.

Comment: @erhan-bagdemir Okay I will do as you say.. Thanks for ur response.

Comment: have a look at this http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You said you modified the code and redeployed it to Tomcat.

You probably just need to restart Tomcat to get it to pick up the new code.  Until then, it will be running the old code and you will get the same error.

How you restart Tomcat depends on which Linux distribution you are running and how you installed Tomcat.