# Working with filepath in Java Code

Tags: java, servlets, filepath

I referred to this [example](http://www.jsptube.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html) and created a servlet application.

It works perfectly fine with the TMP_DIR & DEST_DIR paths that is mentioned in the code(I have created a folder named `tmp` in C drive & also i have created a folder named `files` inside my application folder.

Now I am shifting the code to a linux machine, where this does not work since there is not drive named C: there.  I tried replacing the `c:\\tmp` of the code to `/tmp`(and created a folder tmp) inside my application folder. But its not working. How can I make this code generic? Please advise.

Comment: duplicate of [Error while migrating JSP code from Windows to Linux machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079934/error-while-migrating-jsp-code-from-windows-to-linux-machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is a temporary directory use http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html and look for getTempDirectory(). This should work anywhere

So you need the System Temporary directory which is provided by the system. You can get this either through its path or through the actual File. (IOUtils provides both approaches). Here;s the IOUtil docs:
getTempDirectory

```
public static File getTempDirectory()

    Returns a File representing the system temporary directory.

    Returns:
        the system temporary directory.
```

So if you write:

```
File myTempFile = IOUtils.getTempDirectory();
```

then myTempFile will be where you want to write to.

If some app is asking for the directory by name then you can use getTempDirectoryPath()
which will give the pathname.

In your example I would write:

```
private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = IOUtils.getTempDirectoryPath();
```

or using @dogbane's approach:

```
private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

I'd expect them to give the same answer.

If you are still confused keep asking - that's what SO is for!

UPDATE: If you are doing *anything* with Files it's worth becoming familiar with Apache's FileUtils and IOUtils. There are several things that the JDK doesn't do well or naturally and Apache gives better support.

Comment: I am pretty much confused on how to use this getTempDirectory() in the example that I have mentioned.. Can you explain the same? Am a beginner in java...

Comment: `Readcsv.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable IOUtils
location: class Readcsv` I get this error when adding the IOUtils.getTempDirectoryPath() to the source code..

Comment: You'll need to load the IOUtils class library from Apache (see http://commons.apache.org/io/ and use download). This should give you a jar which you put in your classpath. As you develop try to introduce Maven because it will then look after these dependencies.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust I tried dogbane's approach and it worked fine in windows. But I have some issues in linux. Kindly go through my comments in his answer.

Comment: Why do you use external library IOUtils when you can simply use JDK's File.createTempFile()?

Comment: @Peter because I find it has a number of useful features that JDK doesn't have so I use it. I agree that for this single use case it's possible to use JDK calls

Answer (score 2):

Use [File.pathSeparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) to get system-dependent path separator.

Edited:

If you just want a temporary dir then use [File.createTempFile(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Example file path: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/ConstructFilePath.html

Example temporary file: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CreateTempFile.html

**Edited:**

Saving file in Servlet environment: [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/ReadFileinaServlet.htm)

Comment: It would be great if you can just explain me how to use the same in my code?

Comment: `private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator + "Readcsv" + File.separator + "tmp";` I used this in my code. But I got the error as `javax.servlet.ServletException: \webapps\Readcsv\tmp is not a directory
`

Comment: In servlet environment the only safe way is to save where servlet is installed. Call getServletContext.getRealPath(servletPath) to get a path on the filesystem where your servlet is installed.

Answer (score 2):

The location of the platform-specific directory used to hold temporary files is defined by the property `java.io.tmpdir`.

So in your code you can use:

```
private static final String TMP_DIR_PATH = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
```

Comment: My acutal task is to read contents on csv file and add it to the DB. This task was perfectly done in windows system when I used your code. But when is used the linux server, the csv file is not getting read properly which results saying `0 items has been added in ur database`

Comment: Another Info : I am using the linux server from my windows machine. Using `http://192.168.0.85:8080/Readcsv/uploadcsv.jsp` this in the browser. where 85 is the system number of linux.